# Ambiguous column name using row_number() without alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I'm trying to implement pagination in a query that is built using information from a view, and I need to use the `row_number()` function over a column when I don't know which table it is from.

```
 SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT class.ID as ID, user.ID as USERID, row_number() over (ORDER BY
      ID desc) as row_number FROM class, user
 ) out_q WHERE row_number > @startrow ORDER BY row_number
```

The problem is that I only have the result column name (ID or USERID) that came from a previous query. If I execute this query, it will raise the error 'Ambiguous column name "ID"'. Is there a way to specify that I'm referencing the column ID that is being selected and not from a different table?

Is it possible to specify an alias to the query result itself?

I have already tried the following,

```
 SELECT TOP 30 * FROM (
      SELECT *, row_number() over (ORDER BY ID desc) as row_number FROM(
           SELECT class.ID as ID, user.ID as USERID FROM class, user
      ) in_q
 ) out_q WHERE row_number > @startrow ORDER BY row_number
```

It works, but the SGBD gets confused on which query plan it has to use, because of the small row goal present in the outer query and the big set of results returned by the inner query, when @startrow is a small number, the query executes in less than one second, when it is a big number the query takes minutes to execute.

Comment: There isn't multiple names in the inner query..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `id` in the `row_number` itself.  If you want a stable sort, then include both ids:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT class.ID as ID, user.ID as USERID,
             row_number() over (ORDER BY class.ID desc, user.id) as row_number
      FROM class CROSS JOIN user
     ) out_q
WHERE row_number > @startrow
ORDER BY row_number;
```

I assume the cartesian product is intentional.  Sometimes, this indicates an error in the query.  In general, I would advise you to avoid using commas in the `from` clause.  If you do want a cartesian product, then be explicit by using `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I used the cartesian product just simplify the problem.

Comment: I don't have access to the table alias, that's the problem. In the application, I only know the name of the column. I'm trying to dinamically change any query to change the row order.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the option you already tried, then use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint.

`OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@startrow = 100000) );`

See a description of the hint in MSDN docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx.